# Classes (.cls) copyright

Tags: overleaf, copyright

I want to create my own Journal template, and I would like to use other people's templates in

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tagged/academic-journal

Can I import a class and modify it to my liking?

Is this legally ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no single answer to this question, and legal questions are not answerable here generally, since they depend on particular jurisdictions etc.,

That being said, many classes and packages are released under licences that allow reuse and modification. But you need to check the licence conditions themselves.  As a rule of thumb, if the class or package is released under the LPPL licence, then you are free to develop a derived package or class using that code. If a class or package has no licensing information at all, then it's likely that you have no rights to create a modified class or package from that code.

Copyright is a separate issue: most code is copyrighted by the original author(s) and that copyright doesn't disappear just because the code has an open source licence, so when you produce a modified work, you can't just take the code and call it your own.  Therefore you should preserve original copyright notices in modified versions of code you modify. You do, however, own the copyright to the modifications you make.

Comment: Can we take an example? Can I use this code and modify the use for my journal? https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-gigascience-journal-manuscript-submissions/hwjctgpqtrhs

Comment: that link shows the licence as Creative Commons CC BY 4.0  so you can use it or not subject to that licence @OOzyPal

Comment: Creative Common CC BY 4.0 Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me in the right way.

Comment: Doesn't LPPL require renaming if you want to distribute a modified version? That's an important restriction.

Comment: @cfr Yes, given the context of the question that would seem to be the OP's goal anyway. And the larger point of the answer is that one needs to read the licence to see whether you can use the code and how to use it.